# Understanding boolean property

Tags: objective-c

Using `Xcode5` with ARC , I am creating a property for a boolean :

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL done;
```

than I am using it with `self.done` .

Problem is that sometimes I get error when using it like that. for example(error) :

```
//implicit conversion of bool to id disallowed in-ARC
[encoder encodeObject:self.done forKey:@"text"];
```

With this situation I have two questions:
1. When and why should I create a property with BOOL, and what is the logic behind this?
2. Why I am getting this error ?

Comment: Not that it makes a difference to your question it is more of advice for convention. For BOOL properties the getters are normally something like `isDone` so I would do this `@property (nonatomic, getter=isDone) BOOL done;` only a suggestion as is more of the objective-c convention.

Comment: thanks a lot ,i have learned something.

Comment: @Popeye touched a good point. Forgot about that :). I feel happy when this community loves to complete each other :p

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida in only mention it as a passing comment. Whilst it is convention I do know developers who when doing there own personal projects will just ignore convention completely and do it there own way, but when developing as a group it's always best to stay to convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 2**

You are getting that error because `BOOL` is a **primitive type** and the encoder expects an Object. You can easily solve that wrapping your bool with a literal, like this

```
[encoder encodeObject:@(self.done) forKey:@"text"]
```

This basically convertes to:

```
[encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.done] forKey:@"text"]
```

**Question 1**

You can create a property with `BOOL` because it is more direct that a `NSNumber` initiated with a `BOOL`. For instance, if you wanted to do ifs on that bool with a `NSNumber` you would need to do `number.boolValue` all the time.

The advantage of declaring a property vs declaring an iVar is that it gives you a [KVO](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) ready structure and you have an entry point to get the value and an entry point to set the value. In the case of the `BOOL` this is mainly useful for debugging. Although KVO is also a plus :) ([If you need more info on properties vs iVars follow my answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860078/benefits-of-using-setter-and-getter-methods-vs-direct-manipulation/20860304#20860304))

Comment: So why not just set a boolean as instance variable without a property?

Comment: That is another question and luckly I have given an answer to that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860078/benefits-of-using-setter-and-getter-methods-vs-direct-manipulation/20860304#20860304 . I hope it can answer you :p

Answer (score 1):

As you see `encodeObject:` in

```
[encoder encodeObject:self.done forKey:@"text"];
```

but `done` is not an Objective-C object. Rather it is an BOOL.

BOOL is `typedef signed char BOOL;`

You cant box the `BOOL` type to Obj-C object as `NSNumber` and encode it.

```
[encoder encodeObject:@(self.done) forKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: so making a property of bool does not makes him an object ? . so how can i encode it anyway ?

Comment: No. property can be primitive or an object. to encode convert the bool to an object. as i wrote make it to `NSNumber`.

Comment: Save it as `NSNumber` for instance: `[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.done]`